# Modifying CSS class of Menu Block links?

Tags: theming, navigation, blocks

The Menu Block offers several hooks to override the markup it generates:

```
#theme:
  menu_link__menu_block__1
  menu_link__menu_block__main_menu
  menu_link__menu_block
  menu_link__main_menu
  menu_link
```

However, the variables don't seem to be passed by ref, and if I don't return any string, the links render out null. So, what should I do if I want to just append a custom class to the links and then render them just the default way?

I tried something like in template.php:

```
function MYTHEME_menu_link__menu_block($variables){
  $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my-class';
  return theme('menu_link__menu_block', $variables['element']['#original_link']);
}
```

but it causes fatal error.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to copy the whole function. There is a good example on the [theme_menu_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) page.

You could also check out the [Menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module which allows you to add classes to individual menu items.

Comment: Yes, I know about Menu attributes but I want to avoid that there's-a-module-for-that craziness as much as possible :) I prefer to learn how to squeeze the maximum out of template.php. So, is the decision up to module author whether to pass arguments by ref or by value? Or is it imposed by Drupal's architecture?

Comment: I believe that's imposed. I have used this approach many times in the past without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add class to the anchor link then use this module. [menu_attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes)

If you need to add class in li then use [theme_menu_link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7)

```
function YOURTHEME_menu_link__main_menu($variables){}
```

If you need to add class in ul then use [theme_menu_tree/](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7)

```
function YOURTHEME_menu_tree__main_menu($variables){}
```